# hashTable "properties" C#

Tags: c#, hashtable

1. is someone know what is the hash function that the hashtable use in C#?
2. what is the size of the table? is it proportional to the data i'll insert (e.g 30% more then my data)? or it's a fixed size?
3. can i do the hashTable in one type, like string, or it's alwways return and get an object type? i don't want to do casting every time i get a data from the table....

Comment: Look into generics for number 3.

Comment: @Erno, i need the function that meke the hash. like h(x)=x*3+9. @Stefan, what?

Comment: Google c# generics.  Hashtables are the underlying object for many other c# objects, like the Dictionary.

Comment: it's a hash code, i need the hash function! only the hash table has it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by reading the Remarks section of the [Hashtable documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx). If you do not find enough details about the implementation you can use [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/). To have a hashtable with specific key and value types, you should use [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Comment: i need hash tble, not dictionary. the access to the table is    O(Constant) and to the dictionary it's O(N)!

Comment: *"Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the Dictionary<(Of <(TKey, TValue>)>) class is implemented as a hash table."* -- MSDN documentation for `Dictionary<,>`

Answer (score 1):

1. Object.GetHashCode, which can be overwritten bei each class.
2. No idea, but you should not care as it's an implementation detail. If you want to know it, write a sample program and measure it. But be aware that it might change in the next .Net release.
3. Have a look at Dictionary